# Pass extra arguments to thunk payload in redux toolkit

Tags: redux, redux-toolkit

I'm using the `createAsyncThunk` method to handle an api request with `RTK`.

However, I can't get to pass extra arguments to the `fulfilled` response of the thunk. I can only get the data from the returned promise.

The returned promise has this data:

`{ items: [ [Object], [Object] ], metadata: {} }`

The action:

```
export const getGroupsBySchoolId = createAsyncThunk(
  'groups/getGroupsBySchoolId',
  async (schoolId, _thunkAPI) => {
    const { items } = await fetch(someUrl); // simplified fetch request

    return { items, schoolId }; // this won't work in the reducer, only if I unwrap() the promise in the component
  },
);
```

in the slice the builder I'm trying to get the `schoolId`, but I only get the returned promise.

```
builder.addCase(getGroupsBySchoolId.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
  // console.log(action);
  const schoolId = action.payload.items.length > 0 ? action.payload.items[0].parentId : null; // i want to avoid this an get it from the payload
  state.items[schoolId] = action.payload.items;
  state.loading = false;
});
```

The output from console.loging the `action`, which is of course, the returned promise and the action type:

```
{
        type: 'groups/getGroupsBySchoolId/fulfilled',
        payload: { items: [ [Object], [Object] ], metadata: {} }
      }
```

I could create a regular reducer and dispatch it once the promise has been resolved, but that sounds like an overkill that -I think- shoul be solved in the `fulfilled` builder callback.

Comment: I'm confused what the specific problem is.  Are you saying that the reducer itself is getting a `Promise` instead of a plain JS object for the action? Because the console output snippet looks correct - a plain JS object.

Comment: Hey Mark. I'm getting the plain object, but I would like to have the `schoolId` along with the result of the promise in the plain object, so the `payload` would be `{ items: [ [Object], [Object] ], schoolId: someId }`, which is the object that I'm returning from the `createAsyncThunk`. Thank you!

Comment: Oh, and sorry for your two broken-prod strike of today.

Comment: Haha, thank you! I'm happy to report that I did indeed fix both those bugs pretty quickly :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your last comment, I see what you're asking - you want to know how to get access to the thunk argument in the reducer.

In other words, given this:

```js
dispatch(getGroupsBySchoolId(123))
```

You want to to be able to see the value `123` somewhere in the action when it gets to the reducer.

The good news is this is easy!  For `createAsyncThunk` specifically, the thunk argument will always be available as `action.meta.arg`.  So, this should work:

```js
builder.addCase(getGroupsBySchoolId.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
  // console.log(action);
  const schoolId = action.meta.arg;
  state.items[schoolId] = action.payload.items;
  state.loading = false;
});
```

Comment: Thank you Mark. I have read about the meta attribute in the docs but it was not very clear and I couldn't find much info elsewhere. I appreciate all your efforts put into Redux. Great job!